# Converting Crystal Report RPT to FastReport FRX in C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, fastreport

I'm thinking about migration from Crystal Report to FastReport and as I see, there is [converter](https://www.fast-report.com/en/download/fast-report-net/) from RPT format to FRX format. I tried to compile it on VS 2015, but it doesn't want to. There is zero errors in output, but IDE is telling me it's unable to compile due to errors.

Answer (score 0):

Don't compile the reports. Change the build action to Content.
"Content" means that it is a deployable project item, it signals that the file needs to be copied to the target machine.

Comment: OK, I switched build action to content and hit build solution, but now [I have pretty odd error](http://i.imgur.com/hu5Zzs0.png):

_1>C:\Users\Kwarc\Downloads\FastReport.RPTImportPlugin\RPTImportPlugin.cs(23,17,23,27): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ReportPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)_

But as you can see, IDE is seeing thath namespace, so why builder is not?

Comment: OK, I've finally build it, but manual is worthless. There is no such thing as Fast Report IDE, there is only Report Designer. There is no place to add plugin. There is no config file to edit...